# How to query MongoEngine documents with inheritance?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, inheritance, mongoengine

I've been using a `Node` MongoEngine document for a while.

I am trying to go from a simpe `Node` model to some more specific elements inheriting from it.

## What I've done so far

At first, I was not aware of the inheritance possibility offered by MongoEngine ([see here](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#posts)), so I was using a 'label' field to distinguish between 3 types of Nodes (respectively Keyword, Url and Domain).

#### Here is the original model:

```
class Node(Document):
    project = ReferenceField(Project,
                             reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE,
                             required=True,)
    name = StringField(required=True, unique_with=['project', 'label'])
    label = StringField(required=True)
    volume = IntField()
    clusters = ListField(ReferenceField(Cluster, reverse_delete_rule=PULL))
    x = FloatField(default=random.random())
    y = FloatField(default=random.random())
    connections = IntField(default=0)
    meta = {
        'indexes': ['project', 'label', 'name', 'clusters'],
    }
```

I worked for some time with this model, so the `node` collection is currently populated with thousands of documents.

Then I implemented inheritance by adding `'allow_inheritance': True` to the model and creating the following model:

#### Inherited model

```
class Keyword(Node):
    """ A MongoEngine Document for keyword management. """
    a_keywor_specific field = IntField()

    def foo(self):
        print('this is a keyword specific method')
```

Now this works fine for creating and saving new Keyword documents.

The thing I'm having trouble with is **querying the old Nodes added before this change**.

## Question

If I try to query all the existing nodes, only the one I added after the inheritance change is returned:

```
In [21]: Node.objects()
Out[21]: [<Keyword: Keyword object>]
```

- **How can I access all the Nodes that were added before introducing inheritance ?**
- Is there any way to migrate those old `Node`s to `Keyword`s, `Url`s and `Domain`s based on their original `label` attribute ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened because when you created an inherited model, the old model queries use [`_cls`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document) attribute to query this model's documents. But old documents don't have this field.

Fill in this attribute for old documents.

Regarding your second question.

I think, if you are going to make a migration script that will fill `_cls` field, you can fill its value depending on the value of `label` field.

You can find the required `_cls` values inserting documents for each model.